# Responsive circle with responsive images and text inside

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox, geometry

I badly want to create four responsive circles (two per row) in a container. All circles are supposed to contain some images and text inside - obviously responsive as well.

I've seen many different snippets for responsive circles with a single image or a block of text inside but I couldn't find a solution for my particular problem (which means: all elements combined and scalable).

My current result is a rather unfortunate bunch of eggs, so any help will be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="upper-row">
    <div class="circle">
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
      <p>25%</p>
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
      <p>25%</p>
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="lower-row">
    <div class="circle">
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
      <p>25%</p>
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
      <p>25%</p>
      <img src="http://megaicons.net/static/img/icons_sizes/126/1652/128/aqua-ball-icon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.upper-row, .lower-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.circle {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

https://codepen.io/karuzela/pen/kXKRoK

Comment: What's not working and what's the desired outcome?

Comment: The desired outcome is to have four circles (not ovals) - no matter the screen size. Right now the supposed circles aren't perfectly round, not to mention the fact that the elements inside of them get squeezed after diminishing the size of the screen.

Comment: You can have a look at this https://codepen.io/nuriarai/pen/uIrFf  and http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp  for creating a responsive images and circle.

Comment: You can't use padding to make the element square (and then a circle) AND have content in it. You'd have to position the content absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

```css
        * {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        html {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
        }
        div#mainContainer {
            margin: calc((100vh - ((6/7) * 100vw)) / 2) 0px;
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc((6/7) * 100vw);
            background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
            z-index: 1;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        @media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 7/6) {
            div#mainContainer {
                margin: 0px calc((100vw - ((7/6) * 100vh)) / 2);
                width: calc((7/6) * 100vh);
                height: 100vh;
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

just do whatever you want in the iframe

Comment: Always add necessary information with your code for the readers. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer